# discord authorization token is not working properly

Tags: python, discord.py, token

my discord authorization token stopped working  even though i'm generating a new token to check. but it keep showing improper token has been passed. I did check with someone account token , still results are same. it just  started  happening  from  last month  before that it worked smoothly

tried to update reinstall  python and its library

tried to find on google but didn't found anything related to it

checked on AI  it quote (that my token are invalid try to generate a new one ) and I did that too still no results

Comment: hard to say without seeing any of your code. Please give more information.

Answer (score 1):

How did you check that the Token is invalid?

try this code:

```py
import requests

token = "123456"
   
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f"{token}",
    'X-Super-Properties': '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',
    'X-Discord-Locale': 'en-US',
    'X-Debug-Options': 'bugReporterEnabled',
    'Origin': 'https://discord.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://discord.com',
    'Cookie': '__dcfduid=b3e5c3a0a90a11ed851083055ff4bcaf; __sdcfduid=b3e5c3a1a90a11ed851083055ff4bcaf77aa435c9a1c348e704f04993b5d09e27b541435fc0f7818e8cf57a1eef6d53e; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Fri+Feb+10+2023+07%3A18%3A44+GMT%2B0100+(Mitteleurop%C3%A4ische+Normalzeit)&version=6.33.0&hosts=&landingPath=https%3A%2F%2Fdiscord.com%2F&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A0%2CC0003%3A0; __cfruid=9a271b5836295e409c54941a51ecb05aaf646bed-1693898229; _cfuvid=X_3VUeKT7cNPn9ZB4OZdfg4.v.0qydyhvkdd_om_Ct4-1693898229931-0-604800000; cf_clearance=nIIkjDCp9f8Wk_F0_VwkVk60.siv3C8UoxZCvRw5ttM-1693898234-0-1-ab4e3d0b.8c7758be.79354732-0.2.1693898234; locale=en-US',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'TE': 'trailers',
}
response = requests.get('https://discord.com/api/v10/users/@me', headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("working")
else:
    print("error")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).